# Validation in laravel 4

Tags: validation, laravel-4

Iam new in laravel.

Iam trying to laravel form validation.

my validation code is

```
 $rules = array(
 'studname'=>'required',
 'pmobile'=>'required|digits:10',
 'studadno'=>'required|unique:wys_students,studadno',
 'studrollno'=>'required|numeric|unique:wys_students,studrollno',
 'studgender'=>'required|in:male,female',
 'studdob' =>'required',
 'studbldgrp'=>'required|in:O+ve,O-ve,A+ve,A-ve,B+ve,B-ve,AB+ve,AB-ve,Other',
    );  $messages = array(
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
     'in'      => 'The :attribute must be one of the following types: :values',
);
    $validate=Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages); `
```

output is-:

```
  Student Name :The studname field is required.
  Parent Mobile:
  The pmobile field is required.
```

but, I want  eg: `student name field is required..`
how to change my validation code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$messages = [
    'studname' => 'student name field is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

You can pass the $messages array as the third parameter and you can define custom messages in the $messages array

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options.

Firstly you can change the form field name to student_name and then you will see message "The student name field is required"

Secondly you can write custom messages for each of the fields. In you case it will be:

```
$messages = array(
 'studname.required' => 'The Student Name field is required.'  
);
```

Comment: Sorry .. this code  'studname.required' => 'The Student Name field is required.' is not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rules = array(
      'studname' => 'required',
    'pmobile'=>'required|digits:10',
    'studadno'=>'required|unique:wys_students,studadno',
    'studrollno'=>'required|numeric|unique:wys_students,studrollno',
    'studgender'=>'required|in:male,female',
    'studdob' =>'required',
    'studbldgrp'=>'required|in:O+ve,O-ve,A+ve,A-ve,B+ve,B-ve,AB+ve,AB-ve,Other',
    );


$messages = array(
     'studname.required' =>'The Student Name field is required.',
     'pmobile.required'=>'The Parent Moblie field is required.',
     'studadno.required'=>'The Student Admission Nubmer field is required.',
     'studrollno.required'=>'The Student RollNubmer field is required.',
      'studgender.required'=>'Must be one of the following types: :values',
      'studdob.required'=>'The Student Date of Birth field is required.', 
    'studbldgrp.in'=>'Must be one of the following types: :values',
    );
        $validate=Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide translations of the attribute names in `app/lang/xx/validation.php`.

There's an `attributes` array at the very bottom, just add your attributes:

```
'attributes' => array(
    'studname' => 'student name',
    'pmobile' => 'parent mobile',
    // and so on
),
```

This way you don't have to rewrite the message for every field and every rule. And you can even use those field names across multiple forms.